# Binding button to command inside listview dataTemplate

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding, icommand

I came across this solution that should bind to the root page not the listview which isn't working for me (i'm trying to execute command when button pressed inside listview and pass listview item id with it) right now the (Path=BindingContext.RequestAccepted) is given Cannot resolve property "RequestAccepted" in data context of type object .

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:XamarinApp.ViewModels;assembly=XamarinApp"
         x:Name="RequestsPage"
         x:Class="XamarinApp.ViewModels.Views.CustomerTransferRequestsPage">

<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewModels:CustomerTransferRequestsViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout >
        <Label Text="لا يوجد لديك طلبات حالياً" IsVisible="{Binding EmptyLableVisible}"  ></Label>


        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsLoading}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>



        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding RequestedItems}" 
                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                  ItemTapped="ListView_OnItemTapped"
        >

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>

                            <Label Text="{Binding RequestUserName}"></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding ItemsName}"></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding ItemsPrice}"></Label>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

                                <Button Text="قبول" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference RequestsPage}, Path=BindingContext.RequestAccepted}"></Button>
                                <Button Text="رفض"></Button>

                            </StackLayout>


                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

The viewModel

```
 public class CustomerTransferRequestsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

  public CustomerTransferRequestsViewModel()
    {
        if (GetRequestedItems.CanExecute(null))
        {
            GetRequestedItems.Execute(null);
        }
    }
    ApiServices _apiServices = new ApiServices();

    private ObservableCollection<GetCustomerTransferOrderRespond> _requestedItems;
    private bool _emptyLableVisible;
    private bool _isLoading;

    public ObservableCollection<GetCustomerTransferOrderRespond> RequestedItems
    {
        get => _requestedItems;
        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _requestedItems)) return;
            _requestedItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public bool EmptyLableVisible
    {
        get => _emptyLableVisible;

        set
        {
            if (Equals(value, _emptyLableVisible)) return;
            _emptyLableVisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }

    }

    public bool IsLoading { get => _isLoading; set 
        {
            if (Equals(value, _isLoading)) return;
            _isLoading = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand GetRequestedItems
    {

        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                IsLoading = true;
                var accesstoken = Settings.AccessToken;
                RequestedItems = await _apiServices.GetCustomerTranferOrdersAsync(accesstoken);

                if (RequestedItems == null)
                {
                    EmptyLableVisible = true;
                    IsLoading = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    EmptyLableVisible = false;
                    IsLoading = false;
                }

            });
        }
    }


    public ICommand RequestAccepted
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                //RequestAccepted Logic

            });
        }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like it should work. Try "..Source={x:Reference Name=RequestsPage}.." The **Name=** part is the only difference I see with how I've done it in the past. Would need to setup a test project to verify.

Comment: Tried ... same thing sadly .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need to do is define ICommand property and assign with Command,

Something like this in ViewModel.

```
public ICommand RequestAccepted
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

in constructor you can assign property with command like this,

```
public CustomerTransferRequestsViewModel()
    {
        if (GetRequestedItems.CanExecute(null))
        {
            GetRequestedItems.Execute(null);
        }
        RequestAccepted = new Command(() =>
        {
            //code goes here
        });

    }
```

**.XAML Page**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Name="RequestsPage"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Stack51123113"
    x:Class="Stack51123113.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:CustomerTransferRequestsViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label
                Text="لا يوجد لديك طلبات حالياً">
            </Label>
            <ListView
                ItemsSource="{Binding RequestedItems}"
                HasUnevenRows="True">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label
                                    Text="{Binding RequestUserName}">
                                </Label>
                                <Label
                                    Text="{Binding ItemsName}">
                                </Label>
                                <Label
                                    Text="{Binding ItemsPrice}">
                                </Label>
                                <StackLayout
                                    Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <Button
                                        Text="قبول"
                                        Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference RequestsPage}, Path=BindingContext.RequestAccepted}">
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button
                                        Text="رفض">
                                    </Button>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**ViewModel**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Stack51123113
{
    public class CustomerTransferRequestsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public CustomerTransferRequestsViewModel()
        {
            if (GetRequestedItems.CanExecute(null))
            {
                GetRequestedItems.Execute(null);
            }
            RequestAccepted = new Command(() =>
            {
                //code goes here
            });

        }
        ApiServices _apiServices = new ApiServices();

        private ObservableCollection<GetCustomerTransferOrderRespond> _requestedItems;
        private bool _emptyLableVisible;
        private bool _isLoading;

        public ObservableCollection<GetCustomerTransferOrderRespond> RequestedItems
        {
            get => _requestedItems;
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _requestedItems)) return;
                _requestedItems = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public bool EmptyLableVisible
        {
            get => _emptyLableVisible;

            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _emptyLableVisible)) return;
                _emptyLableVisible = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }

        }

        public bool IsLoading
        {
            get => _isLoading; set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _isLoading)) return;
                _isLoading = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ICommand GetRequestedItems
        {

            get
            {
                return new Command(async () =>
                {
                    RequestedItems = new ObservableCollection<GetCustomerTransferOrderRespond>(new List<GetCustomerTransferOrderRespond>()
                    {
                        new GetCustomerTransferOrderRespond(),
                        new GetCustomerTransferOrderRespond(),
                    });
                });
            }
        }

        public ICommand RequestAccepted
        {
            get;
            set;
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public class ApiServices
    {
        public ApiServices()
        {
        }
    }

    public class GetCustomerTransferOrderRespond
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: That dosn't make a difference .. still can't execute the command from the xaml page directly .

Comment: My problem is that I cant bind to the root (viewmodel) instead inside list view because the source is RequestedItems I can only bind to this list prop not the rest of the viewmodel prop like the commands so when i write Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference RequestsPage}, Path=BindingContext.RequestAccepted}"> ........ I get a ( Cannot resolve property "RequestAccepted" )

Comment: Yes, I created test environment from your code only, I will post both .XAML and viewmode file for your reference (it's demo although)

Comment: I have edited my answer with both files, hope that helps

Comment: Thanks very much .. as it's turns out .. the problem was with Resharper .. for some reason it's keep given the (can't resolve property) .. but when I try to run the code directly it's working .

Answer (score 0):

Inside a ListView, use the 'command parameter' along with 'clicked' to get the command for each button individually.

**xaml**

```
 <Button CommandParameter="{Binding ItemID}" Clicked="ItemClicked" />
```

**xaml.cs**

```
 async void ItemClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
     var Button = (Button)sender;
     String Value = Button.CommandParameter.ToString(); // This gives the Item ID
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well that's work but i wanted to know if there is a way without writing in the code behind page .. (only xaml and viewmodel) .

Comment: Try binding the function in the 'command' parameter instead of 'Clicked' parameter.

Comment: Inside listview i can only bind to  ItemsSource in my case (RequestedItems) list .. the problem now is I want to bind a command in my viewmodel not the list ..so i tried to bind to rootpage which is the viewmodel but i still get and error when i write Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference RequestsPage}, Path=BindingContext.RequestAccepted}"> ........ I get a ( Cannot resolve property "RequestAccepted" )

Answer (score -1):

I use to create an ViewModel for each item in a list. If I already have a model I use that inside the ViewModel, often in a property called Item. So in the binding I will write Item.RequestUserName for example. But this makes it possible for me to add commands to the ViewModel and bind against them.

Comment: ViewModel for each item ?! .. can you give an example ?